# div with ul tag in jquerymobile creating a line space in CSS

Tags: jquery-mobile

http://jsfiddle.net/fLq3C/1/

You can see that here in the fiddle. inside div i have a ul>li tag, but its displaying after a line space. Any idea what wrong i am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default ul properties have a margin-top value, which is what's pushing the li down. I would suggest either giving the ul a class, or using a reset stylesheet so you have to explicitly define the margins.

http://jsfiddle.net/fLq3C/2/

Comment: Indeed, just take a look at my past questions I've spent an hour debugging because of missed capitalization. That's why I love this site.

Answer (score 0):

check your code without    '   #divSearchList' style.. Then it is fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/fLq3C/20/